# Adding New Row to DataSet DataTable

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable, dataset

So I have a problem. I have a MS Access .mdb database file as a DataSet in my project. I am trying to add a new row (record) to the dataset to be saved into the database. Please find the code I am using below:

```
    Function CreateUser(userId As String, pwd As String, pin As String, fnam As String, lnam As String, email As String) As Boolean
    Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
        Using dt As New dbUsersDataSet.tUserDetailsDataTable
            Dim newRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
            newRow("fUserID") = userId
            newRow("fPassword") = pwd
            newRow("fPin") = pin
            newRow("fFirstName") = fnam
            newRow("fLastName") = lnam
            newRow("fEmailAddress") = email
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow)
            Return True
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

I have also tried using an Insert query with the table adapter:

```
INSERT INTO `tUserDetails` (`fUserID`, `fPassword`, `fPin`, `fFirstName`, `fLastName`, `fEmailAddress`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

But I'm not sure how to code that?

Any help?

-----------------------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------

Okay, so here's what I am trying now:

```
        Using ds As New dbUsersDataSet
    Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
            ta.InsertQuery(userId, pwd, pin, fnam, lnam, email)
            ta.Update(ds)
            Return True
        End Using
    End Using
```

I've also tried this:

```
        Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
            ta.InsertQuery(userId, pwd, pin, fnam, lnam, email)
            Return True
        End Using
```

Here's the INSERT query for the TableAdapter:

```
INSERT INTO `tUserDetails` (`fUserID`, `fPassword`, `fPin`, `fFirstName`, `fLastName`, `fEmailAddress`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

However, it still does not work at all, I am quite confused. Nothing happens to the database whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I solved my problem:

```
        Using ds As New dbUsersDataSet
        Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
            Using dt As New dbUsersDataSet.tUserDetailsDataTable
                ta.Fill(dt)
                ta.InsertQuery(userId, pwd, pin, fnam, lnam, email)
                ta.Update(dt)
                Return True
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

I'm pretty sure it's because I overlooked the Fill method.

Anyway, cheers jmcilhinney for your help!

Comment: No, no, no.  You have ignored what I said earlier.  Either use a DB Direct method or use a `DataTable`.  DO NOT use both.  I already showed you exactly what to do so how hard is it just to do it?  The fifth line there uses a DB Direct to insert a record to the database directly.  That's all you need.  Get rid of lines 1, 3, 4 and 6.  Then you'll be left with what I told you to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is adding a row to the `DataTable`, although it's doing it incorrectly, but it's not saving the contents of that `DataTable` back to the database.

Firstly, if you want be able to add a single row then you should, if you haven't already, enable DB Direct commands on your table adapter.  You can configure that in the DataSet designer.  What that does is add `Insert`, `Update` and `Delete` methods to the table adapter that allow you to direct insert, update or delete a record in the database directly, without having to use a `DataTable`.  The code would look something like this:

```
Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
    ta.Insert(userId, pwd, pin, fnam, lnam, email)
End Using
```

If you are going to use a typed `DataTable` then use it properly, which will be something like this:

```
Using ta As New dbUsersDataSetTableAdapters.tUserDetailsTableAdapter
    Using dt As New dbUsersDataSet.tUserDetailsDataTable
        Dim newRow = dt.NewUserDetailsRow()

        newRow.fUserID = userId
        newRow.fPassword = pwd
        newRow.fPin = pin
        newRow.fFirstName = fnam
        newRow.fLastName = lnam
        newRow.fEmailAddress = email
        dt.AddUserDetailsRow(newRow)

        ta.Update(dt)
    End Using
End Using
```

The whole point of using a typed DataSet is to not have to do things like identify columns by strings, so use the proper methods and properties.  Finally, not the `Update` call at the end, which is what actually saves the changes from the `DataTable` to the database.  Otherwise, what's the point of the table adapter?

Comment: Cheers. I tried that second bit before. Problem is I didn't do the update part. As in I added an insert command to the table adapter, did ta.Insert(x,y,z) but forgot the update statement

Comment: No, if you call `Insert` then that's all you do, because it affects the database directly, hence its being called a DB Direct method.  It's only if you makes changes to a `DataTable` that you need to call `Update`, because it's that `Update` method that saves the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.